# How to correct the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action failing when using Power Automate. Input string was not in correct format error

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, connector

I am creating a Power Automate Flow that is supposed to fire when a certain list item in a column on my SharePoint list changes.  I am trying to capture the previous value of that changed column value.  When I test it it is constantly failing on the Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action with the error of "Input string was not in a correct format".  I'm not sure what is wrong as I am putting the title of the list in the script correctly.  Any help with this would be appreciated.

Below is the raw inputs for the request.

```
{
    "host": {
        "connectionReferenceName": "shared_sharepointonline",
        "operationId": "HttpRequest"
    },
    "parameters": {
        "dataset": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/XXX",
        "parameters/method": "GET",
        "parameters/uri": "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Engineering Project Requests')/items(35)/versions(568.0)"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting same error. :/ did you find a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was the issue in my case. Power Automate Since Version token gives you "SinceVersionLabel" instead of "SinceVersionId".
Try replacing it in the code and put it there as an expression.

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Engineering Project Requests')/items(@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']})/versions(@{outputs('Get_changes_for_an_item_or_a_file_(properties_only)')?['body/SinceVersionID']})
```